# Loop for executing multiple methods at the same time?

Tags: java, file, loops

Is there a loop in java that executes multiple methods (or multiple actions) at the same time?

Example:

```
replace(line1, line2);
replace(line3, line4);
replace(line5, line6);
replace(line7, line8);
replace(line9, line10);
```

Loop through a file and replace the strings - they aren't in order.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you asking about multithreading?

Comment: Like multiple actions - multiple replace methods at once.

Comment: Define your need for it to be "at once" and "at the same time". Have you considered using threads?

Comment: That doesn't clarify things. We seem to be asking you always for this. Please read this link and take it to heart if you're going to keep asking questions here: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: like looking through a file and replacing strings with multiple strings to be detected

Comment: more like pulling teeth. I nominate this question as the most obtuse of the day. Either that or vote to close it.

Comment: like in Alice doTogether method... is there an equivalent to that in Java?

Comment: I think the question is how to perform multiple replacements in a single pass in order to prevent a replacement being altered by a subsequent replacement, which could be the case if they were done one after the other.

Comment: @MRAB: have a look at his other questions to get an idea of what he's trying to do.  It's quite simple actually, and so I really doubt it's that complicated at all or that he needs threads. He's just having a tough time asking the question I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this code in your question's edit:

```
replace(line1, line2);
replace(line3, line4);
replace(line5, line6);
replace(line7, line8);
replace(line9, line10);
```

You simply need one method, replace, called by a for or while loop (depending if you know in advance how many times you'll loop). If this doesn't solve your problem, then (*again*), please ask a better and clearer question.

There's no need to use threads to do these all at the same time. You state that "I only need to do this once", perhaps, but you need to call replace at least 5 times in this example, so actually a loop that calls replace 5 times passing in different parameters would work nicely.  If you had an array of pairs of lines, you could loop through the array with a for loop calling replace as you loop.  Again there's no need for a "do together" here but rather a "do in order".

But again you seem to be withholding critical information for unknown reasons.  Again, I urge you to study this link: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)